# Opening Google/YouTube URLs in Chrome by default when Safari is default browser

Tags: safari, google-chrome, web-browser, url

Safari is my default browser, and I like it that way. But I want to open Google URLs (Google Docs, YouTube, etc.) in Chrome by default, e.g., when I click on a link in Mail. Is there a system-level way to set the default browser for a sub-set of domains?

Comment: Give LinCastor a try or ChoosyOSX, I haven't used them since mountain lion so its a toss up if they still run.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to modify plists or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of macOS Sierra there is no way to do this without a a little proxy program which you set as the default browser. This proxy program then dispatches the URL according to some settings and URL rules to the desired browser application.

Building on [tron_jones](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93279/tron-jones)'s comment, I know of three available proxy programs you can use:

- [LinCastor](https://onflapp.wordpress.com/lincastor/) - *Free:* Doesn't seem to be currently maintained
- [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com/) - *Commercial:* Very slick. Easy to setup. Great UI
- [brosel](https://github.com/halloleo/brosel) - *Open Source:* Very lightweight. Setup only for people who are comfortable with the command line. (My own little contribution to this field...)

You would need one rule for the general case selecting Safari by default and a second rule for Youtube URLs which chooses Chrome. Specific setup depends on the tool you are using.

Comment: Choosy's working like a charm.

Comment: I couldn't get `brosel` to read the config file, although I placed it in the different directories mentioned on Github.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Tutorial slides
  
  
  function openURL()
  {
      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      shell.run("Chrome http://www.google.com");
  }

Google has official documentation on the Chrome iOS app’s URI scheme on its developer website.

Simply replace with http googlechrome and with https googlechromes. This means:

http://www.google.com/ becomes googlechrome://www.tutorialslides.com/
https://apple.stackexchange.com/ becomes googlechromes://appsfruit.com/
Previously, it supported an x-callback-url of.googlechrome-x-callback:// This allowed the calling app to indicate its name and URI scheme to Chrome, which would show a back button in the address bar that closes the tab and invokes the specified URI. This feature was removed a few years ago when iOS 9 added the “Back to …” button in the status bar (but the URI scheme still works).

Full tutorial on this [link](https://tutorialslides.com/how-to-make-a-hyperlink-in-ie-webpage-to-be-open-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: Hi,Welcome! If you're quoting something, Use > to make its background yellow.